# LESS could not create a directory in public:

Tags: theming

I am creating a site with drupal 7.15 with bootstrap and using less. But when i reload the page i found the following errors. (dope is my sub-theme name)

```
LESS could not create a directory in public://less/51761ea74e5068.61766466/sites/all/themes/dope/less
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in drupal_pre_render_styles() (line 3311 of /home/seat3/public_html/DOPE/drupal/includes/common.inc).
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in element_children() (line 6300 of /home/seat3/public_html/DOPE/drupal/includes/common.inc).
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your drupal site `files` directory has to be writable by your webserver.

Comment: You mean to say i have to apply chmod 777 to default directory?

Comment: nope not necessarily 777. I suggest reading the [Securing the Files Directory Drupal page](http://drupal.org/node/244924).

Comment: No, the default directory is where your settings.php file is and must not be writable (you will get errors on your status page if it is). The files directory within it must be writable by the webserver, but not by everyone. Permissions on the files directory should be 775 at most.